# How do I get Zen Cart to server XML, JSON (without html headers)

Tags: php, ajax, zen-cart

I am attempting to write a module that uses ajax requests to another page within zen cart.  I would like to mark the page that is to serve the data as "Simple": that is, there will be no headers, footers, or additional characters added to the served page (save the XML, JSON).

Is there a setting within Zen Cart that would allow me to mark this page as "Simple"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a separate .php script which returns just the data you want (without the extraneous information).  Don't use the Zen Cart page infrastructure (i.e. don't put the module under includes/modules/pages, etc.) - just create a file for the purpose you need.

Comment: that was the solution....had a little trouble setting the headers correctly to avoid X-Access errors.

Comment: so where do I create my custom page then?

Comment: The OP was using a page within the Zen Cart structure; creating a separate page and using AJAX is a different question which you might want to ask separately (with all your specific details).  The scope of my answer was just the file which returns the ajax results.